# How to shut ears to office gossip?

Tags: phd, etiquette

Our institute has office spaces for the PhD students with a number of cubicles in the same room. I happen to be an introvert and dislike people talking to me when I am in the office space, or otherwise. But people just love to gossip. They will talk about how bad their supervisor is or how bad my supervisor is, and even though a lot of what they say might be true, it takes a lot of unnecessary toll on me. It makes me very unsettled about my future.

I simply do not understand why people love to talk so much. Are they trying to be helpful? Are the seniors among them trying to guide me? How do I make it happen that I keep going to the office space and not have to make small talk or gossip with other folks there?

Comment: Throw on a pair of headphones - most people usually get the idea and will only interrupt you with important questions.

Comment: That said - I think it entirely depends on what they're talking about.  If the students are making smalltalk about the adviser's latest proposal, then it might be worth listening to.  If it's gossip about one another's love lives - you can probably skip it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not specific to academia and might be better suited for Workspace.se (where it would most certainly be a duplicate).

Comment: The simplest solution I've found: Assume it's all wrong or irrelevant and ignore it. If they bring it to you, cut it off with "Sorry, not interested and busy." . If the problem is pure noise independent of context , tell them to take it elsewhere if you can and don headset or take yourself elsewhere if you can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the headphones idea, and perhaps a baseball cap, worn rather low, would help in a similar way.  Some more ideas:

1. You could put an embroidered sign on your cubicle wall (or a
   calligraphy version) saying something like "If you can't say
   something nice, don't say anything at all" or "If you can't say
   something nice, say it in French."  If those are too blatant,
   perhaps you could post the latter phrase *in French*.  Or choose one
   of the many [images available online](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22if%20you%20can%27t%20say%20something%20nice%22&num=50&newwindow=1&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0CCcQ7AlqFQoTCMHejI_zl8gCFccZHgodS5APyg&biw=1002&bih=860) that represent the concept.
   I particularly liked "NO Trashing OR Bashing Zone."
2. When someone approaches you and starts yakking, there are two ways
   of stopping them:

   (a) Look interested, respond with a wide variety of facial
   expressions, but without *saying* anything.

   (b) Say, "I don't want to lose my train of thought, and I've got a deadline -- can you tell
   me the rest tomorrow?"
3. Start coughing, grab an empty water bottle from your desk drawer, point at your throat, and walk quickly to the bathroom.  If the person is still in your visitor's chair when you come back, point at your throat and communicate nonverbally that you can't talk -- until he goes away.
4. For the really stubborn person who needs a more careful explanation -- just tell them the truth: "I'm the sensitive type, and when I hear negative remarks, I soak them up like a sponge, and they affect me way too much.  This is nothing against you -- but I have to protect myself.  So when I hear you starting to tell me something that's going to affect me this way, I'm going to say, "I'm sorry, Rafael, but I don't want to listen to this."  (And then if he tries again next week, say it.)

Comment: Or maybe instead of posting signs or dropping hints or play-acting, you could just be honest and direct. "I'm in the middle of something right now; let's talk later." or "Excuse me, but would you mind talking somewhere else? It's really distracting." Or if you're feeling particularly spiky: "Oh, just shut up already. If you hate your advisor that much, fire them." You do *not* need to apologize or explain further.

Comment: Why would something awful be less awful when said in French?

Comment: @DannyRuijters - I think that was sort of the point of the joke.  I came across it when I was looking for the correct wording of the standard form.

Answer (score 0):

While it sometimes indeed can be annoying to have people talking when one has to concentrate (and for this, one indeed should have a pair of headphones ready), you could also think about changing your perspective. The point of having an office is also for social interaction and for exchanging ideas with co-workers. When I *really* have to concentrate, then I work a day from home or use a designated space we have for that, but in general, the reason that not everyone works from home but comes to the office is that academic work also is about teamwork, about social exchange, and about getting inspired by talking to others.

Answer (score -1):

Just say "Sorry, I have to interrupt.  I'm working on X."  Perhaps the X will be interesting to them and you've found a new use of their logorrhea and can hone your dialectic skills or even learn something that has value to YOU.

It doesn't even matter if you working on it right then, because now you are.